# Ipad infinate drag scrolling? 

Tags: html, ipad, scroll

How can I make an area on a webpage that can be drag scrolled horizontally on an ipad or iphone, and when you get to the end of content it loops so you continue scrolling and see the first content again?

The jscrollpane has the drag capability: 
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_hover.html

The jquery smooth div scroll can loop but only if the animation is running, not if your scrolling with the controlls: 
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my stab at it.... Complete hackery, but don't have time to improve it.  Hope it gives you something you can work with.  If you'd like to fork and push improvements I would gladly accept it.  Just plain too busy to work on it since last year.

http://github.com/reklis/objc-carousel

UPDATE: Sorry I was brain-dead, here are some JS carousel widget examples:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/infinite-ajax-carousel/

http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

Comment: Thanks for this. This type of development is really beyond me though, are their any plug ins that do any of this?

Comment: Dude this is Objective-C while the question is about HTML/JS.

Comment: @Philippe Lol, I must not have been playing with a full deck that day